# Why does std::tuple decompose into rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++17

Why does std::tuple decompose into rvalue references?

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename, typename> struct same_type;
template <typename T> struct same_type<T, T> {};

void foo() {
  std::tuple tuple(1, 'a', 2.3, true);
  auto[i, c, d, b] = tuple;
  same_type<decltype(i), int &&>{};
  same_type<decltype(c), char &&>{};
  same_type<decltype(d), double &&>{};
  same_type<decltype(b), bool &&>{};
}
```

This compiles without error using gcc trunk.
I would have expected the plain types instead, e.g.

```
same_type<decltype(i), int>{};
```

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9F22pVrxxrFpftgh)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GCC bug. `decltype` applied to a structured binding returns the *referenced type*, which for the tuple-like case is the exact type returned by `std::tuple_element`. In other words, the language tries pretty hard here to hide the fact that those are actually references.

[[dcl.type.simple]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.simple#4):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as
>   follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* naming a structured binding  ([dcl.struct.bind]), `decltype(e)` is the referenced type as given in the
>     specification of the structured binding declaration;
> - [...]

[[dcl.struct.bind]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.struct.bind#3):

> Otherwise, if the expression `std::tuple_size<E>::value` is a
>   well-formed integral constant expression [...] Given the type `Ti`
>   designated by `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`, each `vi` is a
>   variable of type “reference to `Ti`” initialized with the initializer,
>   where the reference is an lvalue reference if the initializer is an
>   lvalue and an rvalue reference otherwise; the referenced type is `Ti`.

Comment: Thanks. I've reopened https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78358